# Firefox 29: Keep "Bookmark this page", hide "Show your bookmarks" button

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar

In Firefox 29, the two buttons, **Bookmark this page** and **Show your bookmarks** are customized together, whence I can't manage to hide one and keep the other one, as in the following picture:

[image]

How can I manage that, please?

Comment: @ajsha answer worked for me. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a [UserChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) file and add the following code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

/* Hide 'Show your bookmarks' */
#bookmarks-menu-button > .toolbarbutton-menubutton-dropmarker { display: none !important; }
```